# .NET Cookies still working even tho' I have disabled cookies in browser. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to disable cookies in my browser, and check that they are disabled in my .Net web app.

One on page I am storing a cookie like this:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

response.Cookies[cookieKey].Value = cookieValue.ToString();
```

On another page, I am retrieving the cookie like this:

```
cookieValue = request.Cookies[cookieKey].Value;
```

I am trying to disable cookies in my browser to make the above code fail but I can't seem to do that.  I am using Internet Explorer 7 and 8.  (I am working with these 2 browsers because IE7 is my company's current standard and IE8 is the future company standard).

In both of these browsers, I went to *Internet Options* `>` *Privacy* `>` *Advanced*, and checked override cookie handling, and blocked both 1st and 3rd party cookies (also deleted any existing cookies/history/temp files).

After doing that, I would expect the above code to not work, but it still works.  I can still set and retrieve values from the cookie.  Any idea why?  I thought maybe the cookies aren't actually getting disabled, but if I go to `hotmail.com`, it gives me an error message saying *"Your browser must allow cookies before you can use Windows Live ID."* so I don't know.

Why do cookies still work when visiting my ASP.Net site?

**Updated 5/14/2012:**

It appears that the cookie settings in the privacy tab are ignored on local intranet sites (I don't know if that is normal or not) so this was giving me problems.  I did however figure out a different way to disable cookies (which I needed for testing purposes), even for intranet sites.  In IE8, I went to *Tools > Developer Tools > Cache > Disable Cookies*.  This worked as expected and i could complete my testing.  However I still have not found a solution for IE7.

Comment: Why do you expect .NET to use Internet Explorer's settings for cookie handling?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: probably because (s)he visits the page using that specific machine using internet explorer?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque If I disable cookies in my browser, and I visit a web app that uses cookies, I would expect the web app that I am visiting to not work correctly.

Comment: @dave823, some settings (e.g. proxy) are shared with Internet Explorer, but I don't think it's the case for cookies. It's a setting that concerns the browser, not the HTTP engine

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the website locally?

I had a similar question [I asked on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/238114/why-is-internet-explorer-8-still-accepting-cookies).

From what I can tell, Sparky was correct. localhost / 127.0.0.1 will always accept cookies regardless of your settings.

Comment: No the website is hosted on a remote server but in the same network